# How can I bundle output from a database query so I can write it to a file

Tags: php

I have this code that gets records from an API and displays it on a page. The code works and the records are displayed correctly.

```
    $allrecords = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $record = getData("https://api.site.com/v2/offers?page_size=100&page_number=" . $i);
        $allrecords[] = $record['offers'];
    }
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $items = $allrecords[0];
//TABLE WITH ALL THE PRODUCTS
    echo "<html><head><style>td{padding:5px}th {padding: 5px;background: #035;color: #fff;}</style></head>
    <body>
    <br/>
    <h3 class='pageDate'>" . $date . "</h3>
    <table id='reportsTable' style='width:80%;margin:20px auto'><thead>
    <tr id='reportRow'>
    <th class='image'></th>
    <th class='title'>Title</th>
    <th class='small'>Price</th>
    <th class='small'>CPT</th>
    <th class='small'>JHB</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";
    foreach ($items as $key => $row) {
        foreach ($row['stock'] as $val) {
            foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $value) {
                if ($value == 1) {
                    $cpt = $val['quantity_available'];
                }
            }
        };
        foreach ($row['stock'] as $key => $val) {
            foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($value == 3) {
                    $jhb = $val['quantity_available'];
                }
            }
        };
        echo
        "<tr>
    <td class='num centerCol'><img src='placeholder.png'/></td>
    <td class='productTitle'>" . $row['title'] . "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . 'R' . $row['selling_price'] . "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . $cpt . "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . $jhb . "</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table></body></html>";
```

There are different users on the system and each has his/her own API key. I have a cron job running every night that needs to run a file that will generate a report for each user. How can I bundle this output table data and write it to html files pls? In other words I don't want to display it I want to put all this table data with the variables into a single variable that I can write to a file.

I have started writing the generate report function but am stuck at generating the html file:

```
function generateReports($con)
{
    $query = "select username, apikey from users";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user = $row['username'];
        $key = $row['apikey'];
        $date = date('dm');
        $filename = $user . '/' . $date . '.html';
        $allrecords = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $record = getData("https://seller-api.takealot.com/v2/offers?page_size=100&page_number=" . $i, $key);
            $allrecords[] = $record['offers'];
        }
        $items = $allrecords[0];
    }
}
```

Somehow my question is not understood This gives me an error:

```
        $content = "
        <html><head><style>td{padding:5px}th {padding: 5px;background: #035;color: #fff;}</style></head>
        <body>
        <br/>
        <h3 class='pageDate'>" . $date . "</h3>
        <table id='reportsTable' style='width:80%;margin:20px auto'><thead>
        <tr id='reportRow'>
        <th class='image'></th>
        <th class='title'>Title</th>
        <th class='small'>Price</th>
        <th class='small'>CPT</th>
        <th class='small'>JHB</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>"
        foreach ($items as $key => $row) {
            foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $val) {
                foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $value) {
                    if ($value == 1) {
                        $cpt = $val['quantity_available'];
                    }
                }
            };
            foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $key => $val) {
                foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value == 3) {
                        $jhb = $val['quantity_available'];
                    }
                }
            };
        "<tr>
        <td class='num centerCol'><img src='placeholder.png'/></td>
        <td class='productTitle'>" . $row['title'] . "</td>
        <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . 'R' . $row['selling_price'] . "</td>
        <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . $cpt . "</td>
        <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . $jhb . "</td>
        </tr>;
        }
        </table></body></html>
        ";
```

Not an expert and the foreach statements is what I don't know how to include in the single string I want to write to a file.

Comment: So how exactly are you "stuck" on this? How to write string data to a file using PHP, should be trivial enough to research. So, what else do you need?

Comment: Well it's not actually string data. It's a bunch of foreach statements in between that also need to be included. I want to write all the table data (echo statements) into a file. So you have to be an expert to ask the right question otherwise your question gets voted down.

Comment: So append to a string variable then, _instead of_ echo-ing it all.

Comment: "_I want to put all this table data with the variables into a single variable_" Do just that. Instead of `echo`ing your content from your first code, store the output in a variable and then `echo` that variable or save it to a file

Comment: There are foreach statements in the echo statement and I don't know how to add them in the string variable

Comment: Agreed. Replace the echoes with string concatenation so that you put all the content in one big string. Then at the end, write that string to a file. Did you try to think through the steps at all? Work backwards - clearly to write something to a file you need to have it in a variable, so hopefully you'd then have seen that you needed to get this data into a variable.

Comment: `I don't know how to add them in the string variable`...this is PHP day 1 basics of working with strings and variables. `$str = "x"; $str .= "y";` ($str will now contain "xy").

Comment: I know how to append a string to a variable. AGAIN my issue is there are foreach statements in the string I would like to know how to include them as well

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, then. You mean to include _actual PHP code_ in the string, is that what you want? Or are you asking how to put a variable such as `$cpt` which is defined inside `foreach` into your output? You're already using that elsewhere in the existing echoed data though, so if you simply appended that data it would already be included. So I don't think that can really be your question? Can you be more specific?

Comment: `This gives me an error`...of course, because you did not terminate the statement where you declare `$content`. Assignment statements require termination with `;` just like any other PHP statement.

Comment: `I know how to append a string to a variable`...so why aren't you doing that? You can't start a statement with a string literal e.g. `"<tr>
        <td class='num centerCol'><img sr`... . I think you meant `$content .= "<tr>
        <td class='num centerCol'><img sr`...etc. Again this is pretty much the basics of PHP syntax, but you seem to have somehow tied yourself in knots over it just because there are some loops in the middle of your two main bits of content.

Comment: You made two echo statements, so you just need two string assignment statements instead. It's identical apart from the destination of the data

Comment: "I have no idea what you mean, then. You mean to include actual PHP code in the string, is that what you want? " Yes so that the variable $content will have the result of the php code (foreach statements) included so I can write that to a file.

Comment: `the result of the php code (foreach statements)`...this makes no sense. loops don't have a result - they have no inherent output (but the code within them might, depending what is written). They're a control structure, not a function or statement with an assignable result. In this case the code within them does assign some variables, but you already later use those in your string anyway so it's irrelevant.

Comment: not result the output generated by the foreach statements that actually print results on a page. How do I include them in the string variable I have to keep appending to. So I can send the content of that variable to a file? $content .= foreach gives me an error

Comment: `How do I include them in the string variable`...by using `.=` like I already explained before. Nothing complicated. See answer below.

Comment: `$content .= foreach gives me an error`...well obviously because `foreach` doesn't return a string (or anything else, as explained above). You need to assign the _actual string data_ (which is defined _within_ the foreach) to the variable. Just like you do with `echo`. You're literally just replacing echo with string assignment, that's all there is to it. You're massively overcomplicating this in your head.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something called file handling in programming. If you haven't worked with it, here is a [tutorial](https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-create-file/) to show you how its done. You can take your variable containing the html structure and put it in the `file_put_contents()`. Here is the complete documentation for [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

By the way this is a simple example of file handling using PHP:

```
<?php
    $file = 'path/where/you/need/file/index.html';
    $content = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";

    // Write the contents in to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
?>
```

**Edit**:

By understanding your requirement further, I came to realise you're having trouble echo-ing the php code (i.e: foreach block). For this, you can simply do what others have mentioned in the comments, echo all the rows into that variable with complete html markup instead of printing a `foreach()` loop and then put that whole markup into a file. Happy coding!

Comment: Don't want to echo anything. Want to write the result of a API call to a file

Answer (score 0):

To get the data into a file you first need to have all the necessary data in a string. Once you have that, you can write the string to a file.

So instead of echoing your data, just assign it to a string variable instead:

```
//create a string with an initial value.
$content = "
    <html><head><style>td{padding:5px}th {padding: 5px;background: #035;color: #fff;}</style></head>
    <body>
    <br/>
    <h3 class='pageDate'>" . $date . "</h3>
    <table id='reportsTable' style='width:80%;margin:20px auto'><thead>
    <tr id='reportRow'>
    <th class='image'></th>
    <th class='title'>Title</th>
    <th class='small'>Price</th>
    <th class='small'>CPT</th>
    <th class='small'>JHB</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

foreach ($items as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $val) {
        foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $value) {
            if ($value == 1) {
                $cpt = $val['quantity_available'];
            }
        }
    };

    foreach ($row['stock_at_takealot'] as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val['warehouse'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 3) {
                $jhb = $val['quantity_available'];
            }
        }
    };

    //carry on adding to the string as needed
    $content .= "<tr>
    <td class='num centerCol'><img src='placeholder.png'/></td>
    <td class='productTitle'>" . $row['title'] . "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . 'R' . $row['selling_price'] . "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . $cpt . "</td>
    <td class='small centerCol' style='text-align:center'>" . $jhb . "</td>
    </tr>";
}

$content .= "</table></body></html>";

//now write the finished string to a file
file_put_contents("text.txt", $content);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I kept on getting an error and it's because I did not encapsulate the <td> data in the foreach loop, which I clearly did not know I should do, so I don't feel like this is php 101, but what do I know, I'm not an expert, which is why I am here asking a question.

Comment: `did not encapsulate the <td> data in the foreach loop`...that doesn't really mean anything as a phrase, sorry. What you did wrong was what I said above regarding the attempt you posted - you didn't terminate the first $content = ... statement with a semicolon, and you tried to declare a string literal without assigning it to anything. That _is_ PHP basics. Whether you can assign the result of a `foreach` to a variable is slightly more subtle, I grant you, but a moment's thought would hopefully have you wondering what such a statement actually outputs and lead you to the correct conclusion.

Comment: Also, most people would tell you not to pepper your code with multiple `echo` statements to begin with, it makes it much harder to manage and control the output, and in some situations that can give you big problems. It would have been better to always build the data this way using the `$content` variable, and just `echo` it once at the end. And then your writing to a file problem would have been trivial - just replacing a single `echo` with `file_put_contents`.

Comment: Also you didn't try to assign the `foreach` to your `echo` statement, so why try to assign it to a variable? It seems like you started trying to change the logic instead of just replacing one destination of the data with another destination (this is what I mean by overcomplicating it). Conceptually, if it helps, you can think of `echo` as simply directly assigning the value to the output stream, rather than holding it in a variable. Then it becomes more obvious that `echo` and `$content .=` are equivalent, interchangeable things.

Comment: at the end of the first line with foreach is a opening brace { and after the last </tr>"; is a closing brace } is what I did not include and what I meant with encapsulate. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah yes in your attempt you accidentally (I think) merged the closing `}` into the second string, and didn't have a 3rd string at all, because you removed the closing `"` at the end of the second string and the begnning of the 3rd one. So that compounded the other problems I mentioned too.

Comment: file_put_contents cannot write the file I get an error Failed to open stream: No such file or directory and the directory is set to 777 and the parent directory is also set to 777

Comment: "No such file or directory" means the file or directory doesn't exist. That's nothing to do with permissions - you can't set permissons on something which isn't there. If you had a permissions problem, you'd get permissions error. Obviously I don't know what path you're trying to write to, or whether it exists in your server or not (presumably not, given the error! Or at least you've made a mistake in typing it into your code).

Comment: Ok I was under the impression the file_put_contents will create the file if it doesn't exist, that is after all the whole point of generating a report, which I am trying to do here. but this code doesn't work either        -- if (is_writable(dirname($filename))) {
            $file = fopen($filename, 'w');
            file_put_contents($file, $content);
        } else {
            die("Cannot create the file");
        } ---

Comment: Yes file_put_contents will create a file if it doesn't exist, but maybe you specified to put it in a folder which doesn't exist?

Comment: And `$file = fopen($filename, 'w'); file_put_contents($file, $content);` will never work because [as per the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) the first argument to file_put_contents needs to be a string (whereas fopen [returns a file pointer resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247019/discussion-between-eagerlearner-and-adyson).